# Scheme/Racket interpreter for math expressions

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, interpreter, mit-scheme

I am trying to make a math-expression interpreter for a project, but I have difficulty in parsing unusual (unary) expressions like `'(- -1), '(- (- -1)), '(* 10), '(/ 10)` and other similar expressions.

```
(define (math-eval expr)
  (define (helper op expr)
    (cond [(and (or (eqv? + op) (eqv? - op)) (null? expr)) 0]
          [(and (or (eqv? * op) (eqv? / op)) (null? expr)) 1]
          [(eqv? '+ (car expr)) (helper + (cdr expr))]
          [(eqv? '- (car expr)) (helper - (cdr expr))]
          [(eqv? '* (car expr)) (helper * (cdr expr))]
          [(eqv? '/ (car expr)) (helper / (cdr expr))]
          [(atom? (car expr))
           (op (car expr) (helper op (cdr expr)))]
          [else (+ (helper + (car expr)) (helper + (cdr expr)))]))
  (helper + expr))
```

This function accepts list and I think that the problem is in the atom? option, but I am not sure how to fix it.
I would be very thankful if you could help me or give me directions how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to build `math-eval` recursively:

- If `expr` is number, return that number.
- If `expr` is symbol of function, return that function.
- If `expr` is list, evaluate each element of list and then use [`apply`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29) to call function (first element of list, `car`) on numbers (rest of elements, `cdr`).

Here is helper function, which returns function for given symbol:

```
(define (fetch-function expr)
  (second
   (assoc expr (list (list '+ +)
                     (list '- -)
                     (list '* *)
                     (list '/ /)))))
```

Examples:

```
> (fetch-function '+)
#<procedure:+>
> (fetch-function '-)
#<procedure:->
```

And here is recursive `math-eval`, working as described:

```
(define (math-eval expr)
  (cond ((number? expr) expr)
        ((symbol? expr) (fetch-function expr))
        (else (let ((op (car expr))
                    (args (cdr expr)))
                (apply (math-eval op)
                       (map math-eval args))))))
```

Examples:

```
> (math-eval '(- -1))
1
> (math-eval '(- (- -1)))
-1
> (math-eval '(* 10))
10
> (math-eval '(/ 10))
1/10
```